# How do I change my DocumenRoot in my VPS server (hostinger)?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, web-hosting

my Doucment root is set to "/var/www/html" and i need it to be at "/var/www/cl"

i already set up my /etc/apache2/sites-available/cl.conf like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName <my IP is here already>
                ServerAdmin <my email here already>
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/cl/cl.wsgi

                DocumentRoot /var/www/cl

                <Directory /var/www/cl/cl/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                Alias /static /var/www/cl/cl/static
                <Directory /var/www/cl/cl/static/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And my cl.wsgi to:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/cl/")

from cl import app as application
application.secret_key = '<already changed this>'
```

my directory structure is like this

```
var/
   www/
      cl/
         cl/
            /static/
            /templates/
            /__init__.py
         cl.wsgi
```

Thank you so much! Just tell me if you need more information.

update:

i have now change my document root to var/www but the problem now is that it doesn,t execute my cl.wsgi so the website just shows me my directories.

[this is what i see in my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sENFT.png)

SOLUTION:
A developer friend help me by accessing my server with me and we found out that
i have been installing apache and wsgi like int the tutorial i watch which is:

> sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi python-dev

but it should be:

> sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi py3

and it solve everything. thank you guys!

Comment: So what happens when you do this?  The Apache config looks approximately correct.

Comment: @TimRoberts it still checks for the html folder which i deleted. i also tried puting all my file in the html folder but it wont run my __init__.py. it only accepts and searchs for index.html inside /var/www/html

Comment: Did you restart Apache after changing the config file?  There's nothing referring to html there.

Comment: @TimRoberts yes i did as it was part of the tutorial. Yeah there's nothing refering to html but it think the default directoryfolder is that of /var/www/html

Comment: You don't have a `DocumentRoot` in your config file.

Comment: @TimRoberts yes. Isn't that the default for linux servers' DocumentRoot?

Comment: I don't care what the default is, if you want a different `DocumentRoot` for your `<VirtualHost>`, then you need to declare it in your config file.

Comment: @TimRoberts oh i see. How do you set one up?

Comment: ??? You already showed us your `cl.conf` file up above  Just add `DocumentRoot /var/www/cl` in the `<VirtualHost>` block.

Comment: @TimRoberts ive already done it earlier still it didn't work, i updated my cl.conf in the question with that addition

Comment: That has to work.  Do you have another config file in that directory that is also claiming ` *:80`?

Comment: yes, i think it should too, all the tutorial i see does this configurations and that wsgi and it works idk why it ignores my conf and wsgi.
@TimRoberts none, it's a fresh server and all i added is what i displayed here which is the conf and wsgi

Comment: @TimRoberts hello sir sorry for tagging, but i would just like to ask if will it help if i delete the 000default.conf, i noticed that it also has port *:80. thanks a lot

Comment: If your setup is going to BE the default configuration for your server, and it looks like it is, then yes, you need to REPLACE the default configuration, not augment it.

Comment: @TimRoberts it wont run without the 000-default.conf but i managed to change the documentRoot inside it . I've updated the question with new detail

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: A developer friend help me by accessing my server with me and we found out that i have been installing apache and wsgi like int the tutorial i watch which is:

> sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi python-dev

but it should be:

> sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi py3

and it solves everything. but it depends on what version of python flask is using. so this worked for me. thank you!